# Android widgets: specific data for each widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm working on a widget, and I actually am at the end of it. It has 3 main classes, WidgetProvider, WidgetService and WidgetFactory.

My problem is that the widget has to display all events on a specific day but users can navigate in the future. So every widget has differents data. Currently, data by day are loaded and stored in the WidgetFactory with a member var. The problem is that I must load data in a thread and I don't know how to load data and then call a redraw of the list without reloading data (Or it'll make an infinite while...).

I have tried many solutions, but everytime, I have infinite whiles or nothing is updating.

I don't know if I am clear, if you need more details, just ask!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. On update, I force the provider to recreate a service for each widget. That new service create a new factory and then each factory is refreshed with it own data.

It's not the best solution, I think. But it works. If anyone has a better solution, I'm open!